# Error cookie/session after upgrade wordpress

Tags: upgrade, error, session, debug

I'm sorry to ask about this problem, but I'm not able to solve. I have upgrade to the last version of wordpress, related plugin and left Civicrm to 5.19.3 and I have the classic problem of the cookie/session.

> We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be
>   enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable
>   cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error
>   persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.") . '
> ' . ts('Site Administrators: This error may indicate that
>   users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the
>   configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some
>   users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain
>   alias like http://myotherexample.org.') . '
> ' . ts('Error
>   type: Could not find a valid session key

It worked fine until upgrade and I don't change the Civicrm configuration. I have the error during some operation as the modify of the directories path, is there a way in order to get the error and not the generic one? In a local installation (copy of the production environment) all works fine.

Error_log.
$backTrace = #0 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(385): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
1 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(833): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Non siamo in grado di caricare la pagina richiesta. Questa pagina richiede i ...")
2 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(828): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKeyCommon()
3 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKey()
4 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(206): CRM_Core_Controller->key("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path", TRUE, FALSE)
5 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller/Simple.php(66): CRM_Core_Controller->__construct("Directories", TRUE, NULL, "CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path", TRUE, FALSE)
6 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(78): CRM_Core_Controller_Simple->__construct("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path", "Directories", NULL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
7 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(263): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path", "Directories", (Array:0))
8 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
9 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
10 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1450): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
11 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
12 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
13 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
14 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(254): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
15 {main}

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same issue now on WP 5.5.3 and Civicrm 5.29.1. It seems to be intermittent, some users get the error while others do not. It appears just at the point where the user submits the contribution form. It is interfering with fundraising, so not good.